# Docker MySQL - remove root password from ENV

Tags: mysql, docker

While running mysql on docker, we can set the environment variable `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` for the container to initialize the database with the specified root password. But then it stays visible via `docker inspect` (or via `docker history` if the env var is set while image is being built).

Is there a way to remove the variable from environment when it's no longer needed (after the initialization is completed)?

##### Details:

If we use a volume to store the database data at host machine, the database will be initialized only once. After that point if we use an image that doesn't have the `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` env variable, the new container runs without any issues because the db is already set up with the password. Is there a way to remove the env variable from the container or better, from the image history so that it will not be visible when `docker inspect` is used? What's the best practice to create database containers that doesn't show passwords easily?
I am using docker compose but not* swarm.

Comment: Note that anyone who can `docker inspect` the container can also `docker run` a new container with unrestricted read/write root access to the host filesystem.  If `docker inspect` is the only thing you're worried about, users who can run it are effectively root already and can do lots of other scary things too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database is already created and resides on a volume, so you can simply:

1. Delete the image and the container (obviously, do not delete the volume). You can use `docker compose down --rmi all` for this.
2. Remove the environment variable `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` from the `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml` or the `docker run` command (also note that the command might be in your console history).
3. Create the image and container again (`docker compose up` in your case) so that they use the same volume.

A good practice is to save the sensitive variables in an `.env` file and use the `--env-file` option in `docker run` (there is also an [equivalent option for Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#env_file)).

Comment: well, thanks, this would work. I am still open to other ways of handling this tho :)